# No. of real roots of $(x − a)^{2n+1} + (x − b)^{2n+1} = 0$

Tags: polynomials

> Let n be a positive integer and $0 < a < b < 1$. The total number of
>   real roots of the equation $(x − a)^{2n+1} + (x − b)^{2n+1}  = 0$ is?

Taking the derivative $f'(x)>0$ Therefore it will cross x axis only once , so it has only **one root**.

Is this solution enough or should there be more tests taking second order derivative etc?

Comment: is it $$(x-a)^{2n+1}+(x-b)^{2n+1}=0$$?

Answer (score 2):

If $f '(x) > 0$ then there is *at most* one solution. You need to use something like $f(a) < 0 < f(b)$ to  conclude that a solution actually exists (and it is between $a$ and $b$).

The unique solution is $(a+b)/2$ - see the answer of @lab bhattacharjee.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$((x-a)/(x-b))^{2n+1}=-1$

The only real root of $z^p=-1$ for odd $p$ is $-1$

Comment: and what is if $$(x-b)^{2n+1}=0$$?

Comment: @Dr, Then $x=a=b$ right?

Answer (score 1):

If
$f(x)
= (x − a)^{2n+1} + (x − b)^{2n+1}
$,
then
$f'(x)
= (2n+1)((x − a)^{2n} + (x − b)^{2n})
$
so that,
as OP wrote
$f'(x) > 0$
if $a \ne b$.

Also,
as Catalin Zara pointed out,
$x_0=\frac{a+b}{2}$
is a root,
since
$x_0-a = -(x_0-b)
=\frac{b-a}{2}$.

Note that this holds
for *any* real $a$ and $b$,
not just between $0$ and $1$.

Even if $a=b$,
there is still only
one real root
since $f'(x) = 0$
only at $x=a$
and $f'(x) > 0$ elsewhere,
and $x=a$ is where
$f(x) = 0$.